# How can I add a ViewCell (created in C#) after another ViewCell created in XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML:

```
<TableSection x:Name="TS2">
   <TableSection.Title>
      ABC
   </TableSection.Title>
   <ViewCell x:Name="noa" Tapped="openPicker">
                    ...
   </ViewCell>
   <ViewCell x:Name="prt" Tapped="openPicker">
                    ...
   </ViewCell>
</TableSection>
```

C#

```
public partial class TableViewFooter : ViewCell
{
    public TableViewFooter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

How can I add a ViewCell (created from new TableViewFooter("AAA",60)) after  second ViewCell in C#.

```
var cmt = new TableViewFooter("AAA",60);
prt.Add(cmt);
```

This code as is gives an error saying:

> Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'value' of
>   'SettersExtensions.Add(IList, BindableProperty, object)'
>   (CS7036)

Comment: You can't add a ViewCell to a ViewCell - but you can append it to TableSection in TableView - for e.g.: try using TS2.Add(cmt)

Comment: 1. The class TableViewFooter  doses't have the initial constructor with parameters. 2. As SharadaGururaj said.

Comment: @ColeXia - These params are implemented I just missed them out to simplify the question.

Comment: @SharadaGururaj - Can you add your comment as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `ViewCell` to a `ViewCell` - but you can append it to `TableSection` - for e.g., try using:

```
TS2.Add(cmt);
```